# NSTimer not firing repeatedly when told

Tags: objective-c

The following only executes once. Why is it, when repeat is set to YES?

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1/3 target:self 
 selector:@selector(updateThingsRepeatedly:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[timer fire];
```

If i understand things right, `updateThingsRepeatedly` method should be called every 1/3 of a second repeatedly. Is this not correct?

It does call the method *once*, however, but does not start a loop, as i would expect.

Comment: Post your updatethings method code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, and do not call `-fire`.

And use floating point numbers for your time interval. I.e., 1.0/3.0.

Answer (score 7):

`1/3` evaluates to 0. Replace it with `1.0/3.0` and you'll be set.

It's the C way to work with numbers. You have to hint the compiler about the desired type of an expression. `1/3` is an integer division, and its result is an integer. `1.0/3.0` is `double`, `1.0f/3.0f` is `float`. You can achieve the same effect with a cast: `(double)1/(double)3`.

`NSTimer` can be set to fire after 0 seconds, which means it will fire once at the end of the run loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this method -

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/3.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateThings:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and if you are using

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0/3.0 target:self 
 selector:@selector(updateThings:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

then you must add it to a run loop.

Discussion

You must add the new timer to a run loop, using `addTimer:forMode:`. Then, after seconds have elapsed, the timer fires, invoking invocation. (If the timer is configured to repeat, there is no need to subsequently re-add the timer to the run loop.)

to add on a run loop use -

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateThings:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it to the run loop:

> Scheduling Timers in Run Loops
>
> A timer object can be registered in
>   only one run loop at a time, although it can be added to multiple run
>   loop modes within that run loop. There are three ways to create a
>   timer:
>
> 1) Use the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or
>   scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: class
>   method to create the timer and schedule it on the current run loop in
>   the default mode.
>
> 2) Use the timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or
>   timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: class method
>   to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After
>   creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling
>   the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)
>
> 3) Allocate the timer and initialize it using the
>   initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: method.
>   (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by
>   calling the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop
>   object.)
>
> Once scheduled on a run loop, the timer fires at the
>   specified interval until it is invalidated. A non-repeating timer
>   invalidates itself immediately after it fires. However, for a
>   repeating timer, you must invalidate the timer object yourself by
>   calling its invalidate method. Calling this method requests the
>   removal of the timer from the current run loop; as a result, you
>   should always call the invalidate method from the same thread on which
>   the timer was installed. Invalidating the timer immediately disables
>   it so that it no longer affects the run loop. The run loop then
>   removes and releases the timer, either just before the invalidate
>   method returns or at some later point. Once invalidated, timer objects
>   cannot be reused.

and, as Costique spotted (+1), you will have to specify an appropriate time interval.

then you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

replace 1/3 by 1.0/3.0. Also use **addTimer:forMode:** to a run loop

Answer (score 0):

You haven't scheduled this timer with the runloop. The reason it fires is because you manually fired it. You don't need to do that, in general, but you do need to schedule it with the runloop. You can use the convenience method to automatically schedule the timer with the runloop:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1./3 target:self selector: @selector(updateThings:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```